# About the addition formula $f(x+y) = f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, arithmetic, functional-equations

Consider the functional equation
$$f(x+y) = f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$$
valid for all complex $x,y$. The only solutions I know for this equation are $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=Cx$, $f(x)=C\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=C\sinh(x)$.

Question $1)$ Are there any other solutions ?

---

If we set $x=y$ we can conclude that if there exists a $g$ for a given $f$ then $g$ must be $g(x)=\frac{f(2x)}{2f(x)}$. By using this result, I tried setting $y=2x$ yielding
$$f(x+2x)=f(x)g(2x)+g(x)f(2x)=\dfrac{f(x)f(4x)}{2f(2x)}+\dfrac{f^2(2x)}{2f(x)}$$

Question $2)$ Are $f(x)=0$,$f(x)=Cx$,$f(x)=C\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=C\sinh(x)$ the only solutions to $f(3x)=\dfrac{f(x)f(4x)}{2f(2x)}+\dfrac{f^2(2x)}{2f(x)}$? If not, what are the other solutions?

Comment: @vadim123 No that is not true. $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and the sine has zero's.

Comment: In that case you take the limit. @vadim123

Comment: @mick What about $f(x) = A\cdot \sin(Bx)$?

Comment: I think that question (2) should be split into a separate question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As leshik pointed out, this equation has plenty of discontinuous solutions (e.g. for $g=1$ it becomes [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)), so let's just consider continuous solutions. $f=0$ is the trivial solution; from now on we will assume that $f$ is not identically zero. We consider two cases:

1. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly dependent, then there is some $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $g(x)=\lambda f(x)$. Since we can replace $f(x)$ with $c f(x)$ and the original equation is still satisfied, we may assume without loss of generality that $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)$, so the equation becomes $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. Now since $f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)$ and $f$ is not identically zero, we must have $f(0) \neq 0$. Then since $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)^2$, $f(0)=1$. By continuity $F(t) = \ln (2f(t))$ is defined in a neighborhood of $0$ and satisfies $F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$. This is Cauchy's functional equation, so since $F$ is continuous $F(x)=rx$, and therefore $f(x)=e^{rx}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{rx}$. Therefore the general solution in this case is:

   - $f(x)=ke^{rx}$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{rx}$.
2. Now suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly independent. Since $f(0)=f(0+0)=2f(0)g(0)$, we either have $f(0)=0$, or else $f(0) \neq 0$ and $g(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. In the latter case we would have $f(x)=f(x+0)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+f(0)g(x)$, so $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would be linearly dependent. Therefore $f(0)=0$.

   Since $f$ is not identically zero, there is no $x$ for which both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are zero, since otherwise $f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$ would be identically zero. Then by continuity there must be some $p$ such that $f(p) \neq 0$ and $g(p) \neq 0$. It follows that $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(p)}f(x+p)-\frac{g(p)}{f(p)}f(x)$, so $g$ is a linear combination of $f$ and its translate $f_p$ (where $f_p(x)=f(x+p))$. Since $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent, it follows that $f$ and $f_p$ are linearly independent. Then since $f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$ for all $x,y$, every translate $f_y$ of $f$ is a unique linear combination of $f$ and $g$, and therefore every translate $f_y$ of $f$ is a unique linear combination of $f$ and $f_p$.

   Since all translates of $f$ are linearly combinations of the linearly independent functions $f$ and $f_p$, this implies that $f$ is differentiable as described in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623557/continuous-f-such-that-the-set-of-translates-of-multiples-of-f-is-a-vector-s). Then by the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622817/differentiable-f-such-that-the-set-of-translates-of-multiples-of-f-is-a-vect/623477#623477), $f$ is a solution to the ODE $\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}+B\frac{df}{dx}+Cf=0$ for some $B,C \in \mathbb{R}$, other than the solution $ce^{rx}$. With the boundary conditions $f(0)=0$ it follows that there are only three families of solutions:

   - $f(x) = kxe^{rx}$, $g(x)=e^{rx}$
   - $f(x) = ke^{rx}\sin(sx)$, $g(x)=e^{rx}\cos(sx)$
   - $f(x)= ke^{rx}\sinh(sx)$, $g(x)=e^{rx}\cosh(sx)$

   Of course, these are valid solutions because of the following addition formulae 
   $$(x+y)=x\cdot 1 + y \cdot 1$$
   $$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$$
   $$\sinh(x+y)=\sinh(x)\cosh(y)+\sinh(y)\cosh(x)$$

We have found all the continuous solutions of the given functional equation. QED

Answer (score 12):

You can take $g=1,$ then your equation reduces to $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).$ Without any additional assumption on $f,$ this functional equation has plenty of discontinuous solutions. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

Of course, once you add some regularity condition (such as continuity, differentiability, boundedness), you can get much more using what Vadim wrote in his post.
As to your question 2 - the same arguments apply, since this is a consequence of the general equation.

Since I do not know which condition you prefer to add, let me just mention that if $g$ is continuous, then equation $g(x+y)=2g(x)g(y)$ has solution $g(x)=0$ or $g(x)=2^{ax-1}.$ To see that, note that if $g(x_0)=0$ at some point then $g(x+x_0)=0$ everywhere. Alternatively, $g(2x)=2g^2(x)>0$ for all $x$ implies that the function $h(x)=\ln g(x)-1$ satisfies $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ and $h$ is continuos. So it is linear. Note, that I assumed that $f$ maps $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ but the situation does not change much if you switch to functions with complex range.

Comment: Thanks but "my master" forbids AC.

Comment: @vadim123 Taking $f(x)=2x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$ won't solve the equation, because $x+y$ could be rational and non-zero while both $x$ and $y$ are irrational.

Comment: It is consistent with the standard (ZF) axioms of set theory without the axiom of choice that the only solutions of $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ on the reals are the linear functions.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: I assume Vadim's answer applies to the Question 2 instead.

Answer (score 7):

Be $B$ a basis of $\mathbb R$ as vector space over $\mathbb Q$, then it is immediately clear that for any $b,b'\in B$, we can independently choose $f(b)$ and $f(b')$ because the addition theorem doesn't relate values in different $\mathbb Q$-subspaces of $\mathbb R$.

We can remove this ambiguity by additionally demanding that $f$ is continuous. Then the values of $f$ on the rational numbers determine the values on the irrational numbers by continuity. Therefore in the following I'll assume $f$ is continuous.

First, I'll put forward a few general properties of the solutions:

**Observation 1:** For any fixed $g(x)$, the set $V_g:=\{f:f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)\}$ is a vector space.

*Proof:*

- The function $f(x)=0$ obviously is in $V_g$.
- if $f_1\in V_g$ and $f_2\in V_g$ then also $f=f_1+f_2\in V_g$:
  $$\begin{align}
    f(x+y) &= f_1(x+y)+f_2(x+y)\\
    &= f_1(x)g(y)+f_1(y)g(x) + f_2(x)g(y)+f_2(y)g(x)\\
    &= (f_1(x)+f_2(x))g(y) + (f_1(y)+f_2(y))g(x)\\
    &= f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x)
  \end{align}$$
- If $f\in V_g$, then also $F=\alpha f\in V_g$:
  $$F(x+y)=\alpha f(x+y) = \alpha (f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)) = \alpha f(x)g(y) + \alpha f(y)g(x) = F(x)g(y)+F(y)g(x)$$

This observation means that we only have to find a basis for each $g$, and can then get the other functions as linear combinations.

Note that in proving the vector space property, we've actually already proved the

- First solution: $\color{red}{f(x)=0}$

**Observation 2:** If $f(x)$ is a solution with $g(x)$ as "companion function", then for any $\alpha$, $f_\alpha(x):=f(\alpha x)$ is a solution with $g_\alpha(x):=g(\alpha x)$ as companion function.

*Proof:*
$$f_\alpha(x+y) = f(\alpha(x+y)) = f(\alpha x+\alpha y) = f(\alpha x)g(\alpha y)+f(\alpha y)g(\alpha x) = f_\alpha(x)g_\alpha(y)+f_\alpha(y)g_\alpha(x)$$

This scaling property will prove quite handy.

**Observation 3:** If $f(x)$ is a solution with the function $g(x)$, then $f_\lambda(x):=f(x)\mathrm e^{\lambda x}$ is a solution with the function $g_\lambda(x):=g(x)\mathrm e^{\lambda x}$.

*Proof:* $f_\lambda(x+y) = f(x+y)\mathrm e^{x+y} = (f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x))\mathrm e^{x+y} = f(x)\mathrm e^xg(y)\mathrm e^y + f(y)\mathrm e^yg(x)\mathrm e^x = f_\lambda(x)g_\lambda(y)+f_\lambda(y)g_\lambda(x)$.

Note that this observation already allows to derive some new solutions in addition to those found in the question, for example $\mathrm e^x\sin x$ is another such function.

**Observation 4:** If $g(0)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ is the only element of $V_g$

*Proof:* We have $f(x) = f(0+x) = f(0)g(x) + g(0)f(x)$. Since by assumption $g(x)=0$, we get $f(x) = f(0)g(x)$. But for $x=0$ this means $f(0) = f(0)g(0) = 0$, therefore $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Observation 4 means that for any non-trivial solution, we have $g(0)\ne 0$.

**Observation 5:** If for any $x_0$ we have $f(x_0)=0$, then $f(0)=0$.

*Proof:* We have $0 = f(x_0) = f(0 + x_0) = f(0)g(x_0) + f(x_0)g(0) = f(0)g(x_0)$. So either $f(0)=0$ or $g(x_0)=0$. In the latter case, $f(x+x_0) = f(x)g(x_0)+f(x_0)g(x)=0$ for all $x$, that is, we would have the trivial solution, which of course also has $f(0)=0$ (as can be seen also directly by inserting $x=-x_0$).

Observation 5 means we have at most three types of solutions:

1. Solutions which are zero at some $x_0\ne 0$ (and additionally at $x=0$).
2. Solutions which are zero only at $x=0$.
3. Solutions that are nowhere zero.

Let's first consider the case that there's an $x_0\ne0$ so that $f(x_0)=0$.
Since we have proved that $g(x_0)=0$ only admits the trivial solution, we can in the following assume $g(x_0)\ne 0$.

**Observation 6:** If $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(y_0)=0$, then $f(x_0+y_0)=0$.

*Proof:* This follows directly from the sum formula: $f(x_0+y_0) = f(x_0)g(y_0) + g(x_0)f(y_0) = 0$

From this observation one gets immediately:

**Observation 7:** If $f(x_0)=0$, then $f(n x_0)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

*Proof* by induction:

- For $n=0$, we have proved it in observation 4.
- For $n=1$, it is just the assumption.
- If we have proven it for $n$, 
  $f((n+1) x_0) = f(n x_0 + x_0) = 0$ by observation 5.

**Observation 8:** If $f(x_0)=0$, then $f(-x_0)=0$.

*Proof:* $0 = f(-x_0 + x_0) = f(-x_0)g(x_0)+f(x_0)g(-x_0) = f(-x_0)g(x_0)$. Since $g(x_0)\ne 0$, we must have $f(-x_0)=0$

Observations 7 and 8 together mean that if $f(x_0)=0$, then $f(nx_0)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

**Observation 9:** There's a minimal $x_0$ so that $f(x_0)=0$.

*Proof:* If there were no such minimal $x_0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ we would find an $x_1<\epsilon$ so that $f(x_1)=0$. But with that and the fact that with $x_1$, also all $nx_1$ are zeros of $f$, it is easy to create a series of zeros converging to an arbitrary real number, so we would have $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

To simplify our notation, we can use the scaling property (observation 2) to assume without loss of generality that the first positive zero of $f(x)$ is $1$. Then the previous result mean that $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$.

**Observation 10:** There are no non-integer values $x_0$ so that $f(x_0)=0$.

*Proof:* If there were such a value, then $f(x_0-\lfloor x_0\rfloor)=0$. But $0<x_0-\lfloor x_0\rfloor<1$, contrary to the assumption that $1$ is the smallest positive zero of $f$.

**Observation 11:** $f(x+n) = f(x)g(1)^n$

*Proof:* We have $f(x+1)=f(x)g(1)$, which implies $f(x+n)=f(x)g(1)^n$. On the other hand, a direct application of the sum formula gives $f(x+n)=f(x)g(n)$. Thus $g(n) = g(1)^n$.

**Observation 12:** $g$ vanishes for all $n+\frac12$.

*Proof:* For $n$ odd, we get $0 = f(n) = f(\frac n2+\frac n2) = 2f(\frac n2)g(\frac n2)$. Since $n$ is odd, $f(\frac n2)\ne 0$, and therefore $g(n/2)=0$.

To simplify the further considerations, use the vector space property (observation 1) together with the knowledge that $f(\frac12)\ne0$ to fix without loss of generality $f(\frac12)=1$.

**Observation 13:** $g(x)=f(x+\frac12)$.

*Proof:* By the addition property, $f(x+\frac12)=f(x)g(\frac12)+g(x)f(\frac12)$. Bur $g(\frac12)=0$ (observation 12) and $f(\frac12)=1$ (we just fixed that value).

**Observation 14:** $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)+f(x+1)f(y)$

*Proof:* $g(x+y) = f(\frac12+x+y) = f(\frac12+x)g(y) + f(y)g(\frac12+x) = g(x)g(y)+f)y=f(\frac12+\frac12+x)$.

**Observation 15:** $g(n) = g(1)^n$

*Proof:* By induction: $g(n+1) = g(n)g(1) + f(n+1)f(1) = g(n)g(1)$.

Note that the same recursion formula can be used also backwards, so it is true for all $n$.

Now we can use observation 3 (the exponential factor property) to reduce our considerations to the two cases $g(1)=1$ and $g(1)=-1$. Then of course $g(n)=(\pm 1)^n$. Especially $g(-1)=g(1)$ and $g(2)=1$.

Comment: All those observations should rather be propositions! =D

Answer (score 6):

Some partial results:

Assume henceforth that neither $f$ nor $g$ is constant and $0$.
Take $y=0$, we get $$f(x)=f(x)g(0)+f(0)g(x),\textrm{ or }f(x)(1-g(0))=f(0)g(x)$$
 then either $g(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$, or

> $$f(x)=\frac{f(0)}{1-g(0)}g(x)$$
>   Substituting $x=0$ gives $g(0)=1-g(0)$ so $g(0)=0.5$, and hence $f(x)=2f(0)g(x)$.  Substituting into the original gives $$2f(0)g(x+y)=2f(0)g(x)g(y)+2f(0)g(y)g(x)$$ whence $$g(x+y)=2g(x)g(y)$$ As Kunnysan points out, $g(x)=e^x/2$ satisfies this.  Taking $x=n-1, y=1$ lets us prove inductively that $g(n)=2^{n-1}g(1)^n$.

Suppose now that $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$.

Now, taking $y=-x$, we have  $$0=f(0)=f(x)g(-x)+f(-x)g(x)$$  Rearranging, we have (provided both expressions exist)$$\frac{f(x)}{f(-x)}=-\frac{g(x)}{g(-x)}$$

Hence if $f$ is even, then $g$ is odd and vice versa.

I think you'll have a hard time proving that the families you have are everything, unless you have some sort of differentiability assumption.

Comment: $g(x+y)=2g(x)g(y)$ and that would give you a solution $g(x)=\frac{e^x}{2}$

Comment: Nice, but im a bit confused now. Why doesnt $\sin$ pop out of these equations ?

Comment: Sine pops out of the "general" case where $f(0)=0$, $g(0)=1$.  The gray box is the "special" case where $f$ is a multiple of $g$.