# Solution of $f(3x)=\frac{f(x)f(4x)}{2f(2x)}+\frac{f^2(2x)}{2f(x)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, arithmetic, functional-equations

What are the analytic solutions to $f(3x)=\dfrac{f(x)f(4x)}{2f(2x)}+\dfrac{f^2(2x)}{2f(x)}$?

Are there solutions that do not satisfy a linear first or second ODE ?

See also : [About the addition formula $f(x+y) = f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444517/about-the-addition-formula-fxy-fxgyfygx)

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a solution.

Comment: The functions $x\mapsto e^{cx}$, $c$ constant, are solutions as well.

Comment: Any polynomial $f$ must have degree $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Those examples all satisfy a first or second ODE. Just saying.

Comment: Does "a first or second ODE" mean any first order or second order ODE?

Comment: Or maybe just linear ODE with constant coefficients? (I don't believe we can prove that a function doesn't satisfy any 1st or 2nd order ODE, because there's no general theory for nonlinear ones)

Comment: See the edit Yuriy. Linear it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, just some **experimental** results.

As we are asked for analytic solutions, we can simply substitute a general Taylor series:

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+\dots$$

into the equation:

$$2f(x)f(2x)f(3x)-f(x)^2 f(4x)-f(2x)^3=0$$

Discounting the extra solution $f(x)=0$, which doesn't satisfy the original equation.

**1)** First case $a_0 \neq 0$. Then with some help from Mathematica, we obtain:

$$a_1 \in \mathbb{C}$$

$$a_{ n \geq 2}=\frac{a_1^n}{n! ~a_0^{n-1}}$$

Which makes the general solution for this case:

$$f(x)=a_0 \exp \left( \frac{a_1}{a_0}x \right)$$

Which satisfies 1st order linear ODE with constant coefficients. This fits both the solutions proposed by Christian Blatter.

**2)** Second case $a_0=0$. Here it becomes more interesting.

First we notice that $a_1 \neq 0$. Because experimentally from $a_1=0$ follows $a_{n \geq 2}=0$ as well, which makes $f(x)=0$, the solution we have already discounted.

If $a_1 \neq 0$ then we have:

$$a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{C}$$

And the following recurrence relations:

$$a_4=\frac{3 a_1 a_2 a_3-a_2^3}{3 a_1^2}$$

$$ a_5=\frac{4 a_1 a_2 a_4+3 a_1 a_3^2-2 a_2^2 a_3}{10 a_1^2}$$

$$a_6= \frac{5 a_1 a_2 a_5+23 a_1 a_3 a_4-2 a_2^2 a_4-5 a_2 a_3^2}{65 a_1^2}$$

Not sure if I see the pattern in the general case, however experimentally:

**2a)** If we take $a_1=1$, $a_2=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_3=\frac{1}{6}$ then we get the exponential function again.

**2b)** If we take $a_2=0$, it then follows that $a_{2n}=0$ for any $n$, so we obtain an odd function (note that an even function is not a solution, as the above shows, $a_1 \neq 0$).

The first few coefficients are given by:

$$a_3 \in \mathbb{C}$$

$$a_5=\frac{3a_3^2}{10 a_1}$$

$$a_7=\frac{3a_3^3}{70 a_1^2}$$

$$a_9=\frac{a_3^4}{280 a_1^3}$$

$$a_{11}=\frac{3a_3^5}{15400 a_1^4}$$

$$a_{13}=\frac{3a_3^6}{400400 a_1^5}$$

$$a_{15}=\frac{3a_3^7}{14014000 a_1^6}$$

$$a_{17}=\frac{9a_3^8}{1905904000 a_1^7}$$

The denominators are partial products in the sequence $$10 \cdot 7 \cdot 4 \cdot 55 \cdot 26 \cdot 35 \cdot 136 \cdot \cdots$$

This seems promising as there's no apparent pattern.

Taking $a_3=0$ leads us to the solution $f(x)=a_1 x$, which a more general case of Rohan's comment.

---

I'll look into this further at a later date, but the question itself is not clear to me because I don't believe it's possible to prove that some function given by its Taylor series doesn't satisfy **any** first order or second order ODE, as there's so many nonlinear equations possible. If we only consider linear ODEs with constant coefficients, the problem becomes more simple.